# Array Push Not Working In Firestore Callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get multiple documents from firestore and add them to an array, returning that array. For some reason, the `array.push()` is not adding the data to the array. Is it because of the scope? There are no errors so I doubt that is the case.

Why won't the item get pushed into the array?

This is my current approach. I have also tried using a promise instead of an observable. (Keeping count of how many docs had returned and resolving once they all had)

```
getFriendsData(ids: string[]): Observable<User[]>{
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        let lstFriends: User[] = [];
        if (ids != null && ids.length > 0){
            ids.forEach((sFriendID) => {
                this.firestore.collection('users').doc(sFriendID).get().subscribe((data) => {
                    console.log("User Fetched", <User>{id: sFriendID, ...data.data()});

                    lstFriends.push(<User>{id: sFriendID, ...data.data()});

                    console.log("After push", lstFriends);

                    observer.next(lstFriends);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, the user is not added to the array but there are no errors.
[image]

Comment: Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. So you need to make sure that you only access the `lstFriends` **after** `subscribe((data) => {` has fired. Typically you do that by putting the code that needs the `lstFriends` **into** that callback, or attaches to an observer that fires once `lstFriends` is modified.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, isn't that what I am doing? I only add to the array once the call returns data. And the code consuming the data only accesses once the observable transmits that the array has been pushed to. But the array isn't being modified and returns an empty one.

Comment: Ah... now I see where you log the array. Indeed I don't see why that would be empty. I'd recommend logging simple values (e.g. `console.log(data.data().id)`) though, as the Chrome dev console makes it hard to see the async behavior otherwise.